# Mathematica - Create a custom plotter from regularly used code

Tags: plot, module, wolfram-mathematica, block

I've been searching the web for the past hours trying to find some way to implement a routine/function in Mathematica that basically does your plotting. I've written code that only needs a two dimensional field, say:

```
dx/dt = x-x^2

dy/dt = y-y^2.
```

What I do from here on is that I solve for the fix points and then numerically integrate a few trajectories and plot them together...

Now the question is can I somehow compose my code into a function like in Matlab? I've been researching the concepts of Module, and Block but it seems to be impossible for me to return the plot.

So for clarification I want to be able to write a function that takes as an argument only the field, and then returns a plot of the field to me ( with customised trajectories from the fix points etc..

```
CustomPlotField[dxdt,dydt] := ............
```

Since I do a lot of stuff for the plotting, the code is pretty large so i copy pasting chunks of code for plots that I'm doing regularly feels a bit annoying.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can perfectly well return a plot. show what you have tried ...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you are on the right track looking at modules:

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ModulesAndLocalVariables.html

To return the plot just evaluate it as the last expression in the body of the Module. Or use an explit Return.

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Return.html